# Should i upgrade linux-headers-generic-lts-trusty and linux-image-generic-lts-trusty?

Tags: 12.04, server

These updates are being offered to me through `apt-get upgrade`, they seem like kernel updates but don't follow the other kernel naming convention, so I'm a bit leery of installing it. I figure if its being offered there should be some reason. I'd like to know what that reason is.

I'm on 12.04.5, 3.13.0-32-generic. I have run `apt-get update/upgrade` these two packages are the ones that are left (not auto upgraded). Please let me know if there is any other information needed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's normal...  (sorry for not answering you in chat.  It looked much more complex)

See the [official Ubuntu documentation](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) on 12.04.5 + 14.04 Hardware Enablement Stack Policies and Procedures.